# How to show usages in UI within Intellij IDE

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I accidentally disabled the "show usages" UI feature in intellij and I cannot seem to figure out how to find it.

For example, it would sit above any fields, methods, or classes that were used within the project.

So, if I used the field in [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2QBfG.png), it would show "usages" which I could highlight and go to its use in the project.

How do I restore this feature?

Comment: Try pressing Shift+Shift, then type "Show usages" command. The result will point you to all relevant commands and settings (including shortcuts).

Comment: Please check Inlay Hints settings under `Settings/Preferences | Editor | Inlay Hints`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ctrl + b` to show usages

`ctrl + alt + b` to show implementations